# Spring: Create file with bean instead of just calling the object

Tags: spring, spring-boot, resttemplate

I have seen the following suggestion in some tutorials.

Does it make sense to define a file such as this instead of just using `RestTemplate()` ?

If yes, what are the advantages?

```
@Configuration
public class RestTemplateConfig {
    @Bean
    public RestTemplate getRestTemplate() {
        return new RestTemplate();
    }
}
```

and then use it in your class like

```
@Autowired
private RestTemplate restTemplate;
```

(suggest an edit if the question is not asked correctly)

Comment: The `RestTemplate` is a heavy object to construct and you want to use DI to get your objects you need instead of creating them when needed (as a general rule of thumb). So as this is a heavyweight object you only want 1 instance which you use in different places.

Comment: ok agreed, but then why not use DI for all objects? Which objects should have explicit beans ? we cant create beans for all of them

Comment: Generally things that make your appllication infrastructure should be beans, things like entities, helpers etc. shouldn't be. But as stated that is a rule of thumb...